# Multiple .htaccess files

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I'm relatively new to htaccess files and I'm trying to get my URL to look SEO friendly.

It says to change my htaccess.txt to .htaccess to allow URL overwrite but I have multiple htaccess files and don't know which to switch and what to do.

My goal is to get from: 
http://www.sunshineorlandorentals.com/component/bookman/?PropertyId=1609

to:
http://www.sunshineorlandorentals.com/location/1609

Comment: first thing to remember: in a htaccess you ReWrite _from_ `http://www.sunshineorlandorentals.com/location/1609` (what's in the browser's address bar) _to_ `http://www.sunshineorlandorentals.com/component/bookman/?PropertyId=1609` (what php actually gets)

Comment: you might have several htaccess files in several folder-levels. The highest one (in root) ist the most important one.

Comment: I have multiple .htaccess files in the root. One named _.htaccess one named htaccess.txt and one named htaccess2.txt

Comment: only the one that is _exactly_ `.htaccess` is active. the others are backups or smth..

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused about the multiple .htaccess files. The only file which is working is without any extension that means .htaccess is the right file. You can delete other .htaccess.txt files. Download them before Delete as **Backup**.

To redirect your current url to new one -- Simply ADD below line of code into your .htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301 /pagename.php http://www.example.com/pagename.html
```

Here pagename.php is your old url without Domain name 
and pagename.html is new url with same Domain name, Replace example.com with yours one.

And your new Url http://www.sunshineorlandorentals.com/location/1609 is completely Seo friendly. Try to make all your urls like same in future.

Thanks

Comment: Hey so if I have multiple URLs that will be rewritten will that apply to all URLs or just one of them?

I went into my Joomla panel and allowed SEF and URL rewrite and it works for this link:
http://www.sunshineorlandorentals.com/index.php/vacation-villa-communities/terra-verde-resort

but it stopped working for this link:

http://www.sunshineorlandorentals.com/index.php/component/bookman/?PropertyId=10

Comment: Hey so if I have multiple URLs that will be rewritten will that apply to all URLs---

To edit the Menu item URL (Alias), navigate to Joomla admin panel > Menus > Main menu tab. Open the Menu item required and find the Alias field next to the Menu Item title or under it. Type new URL into the Alias field and use the Save or Save & Close buttons to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore all other files.
You just need to enable sef urls and sef rewrites on Joomla sites (in joomla config setting).

Create new hidden menu with alias 'location' pointing to your component that's it.